EasyOCR error when passing a list of languages to a Reader instance
I'm workin on a project that reads text from frames extracted from a video. However, when I was trying to run a function to implement EasyOCR, in VS "output" it started loading model from 0.0% and at about 2.0% I received an error that had something to do with encoding. To test things, I made a small test code:
import cv2
import easyocr

image_path = 'test.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(image_path)

lang_list = ['en', 'ru']

[el.encode('utf-8') for el in lang_list]

reader = easyocr.Reader(lang_list, gpu=False)

text = reader.readtext(img)

print(text)

that when run, gives the same error. I even added UTF-8 encoding to it, still same error.
Now, the error I get is this:
File "d:\Python Projects\easyocr_test.py", line 12, in <module>
    reader = easyocr.Reader(lang_list, gpu=False)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\easyocr.py", line 92, in __init__
    detector_path = self.getDetectorPath(detect_network)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\easyocr.py", line 253, in getDetectorPath
    download_and_unzip(self.detection_models[self.detect_network]['url'], self.detection_models[self.detect_network]['filename'], self.model_storage_directory, self.verbose)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\utils.py", line 628, in download_and_unzip
    urlretrieve(url, zip_path, reporthook=reporthook)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 277, in urlretrieve
    reporthook(blocknum, bs, size)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\easyocr\utils.py", line 728, in progress_hook
    print(f'\r{prefix} |{bar}| {percent}% {suffix}', end='')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2588' in position 12: character maps to <undefined>

How could I fix that error ?

What do you think [el.encode('utf-8') for el in lang_list] does? It creates a list with binary data that is never used.

Well, even If I pass a regular lang_list without this encoding, it still gives the same error.
